# Is it just me or the EeePC's wireless is woefully underpowered?

Tags: wireless-networking, eee-pc

Just set up a network at home with an el cheapo TP-Link router sharing my ADSL. (Properly secured, nacht.) I have an Acer Aspire 5570Z and an EeePC 1000HD. The Acer's wi-fi connection is rock solid, while the Eee's is flaky as hell, comes and goes on a whim, both in Linux and Windows. Both in the same room as the router.

Anybody has a similar experience?

Comment: can find 3 different asus eee pc related questions with all different tags, eee, eee-pc, eeepc. This isn't perfect ...

Comment: Maybe some "ad hoc tag auto-renaming system" with a dictionary of common synonyms?

Comment: Not meant to be a forum type site.. -1

Comment: @barfoon: What? He has a problem, and he wants to know if it's universal (in which case he's probably screwed) or if it's just him (in which case it may be fixable). How is that inappropriate?

Comment: (About the tags: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10227/retag-request-merge-eee-eeepc-eee-pc-on-super-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue became moot, as I sold the machine. Oddly, it worked well with another AP elsewhere, which suggests a combination client/AP problem.

I have an Acer Aspire 5570Z with no problems at all. Stable connection with any AP, anywhere.

Comment: Sometimes a particular wifi router will fail to talk to a particular wifi device; So I think you're on to something. EG older unpatched netgear MR814s cannot talk to the July version of the MacBook Pro reliably.

Answer (score 1):

I'm typing this on a 1000HA, which has the same network hardware as the HD. [InSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider) shows that reception is comparable to what I'm getting on my ThinkPad R500 (currently -60 dBm for my associated connection on the eeePC vs. -50 dBm on the ThinkPad). The eeePC is even picking up more networks than the ThinkPad, though not to the point of interfering with my connection.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe this would be a possibly warranty issue to bring up.  Might be worth a try if you have tried it in 2 different operating systems and same results.  At first I would try different drivers and different OS's, but sounds like you did that. It is worth a shot if it is still under warranty.

Comment: I bought it in the US, and I am in Brazil. Waaah.

Comment: Might be worth a shot to try a different router if you have access to one just to see if you see the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I own the 701 4G EeePC.

I can't remember how the wireless was on the default Xandros OS, but on my current Ubuntu install, I find the wireless is perfectly fine is you have the correct drivers.  In fact, it even tends to pick up a stronger signal then most other laptops and even my desktop (has a wireless PCI chip.)

However, I used to use a not so good driver, and it was painful to use.  Wouldn't connect to routers that well even though it displayed a good signal, and it cut in and out often.

Try looking to see if there are better drivers for it.  You do have a different EeePC, but it is worth a shot.